# how can know lenght my array in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

i have this code in JavaScript

```
    var items_in_cart = [];
    items_in_cart['rr'] = 1;
    items_in_cart['mm'] = 2;
alert(items_in_cart.length);
```

i get 0

if change code to

```
items_in_cart[50] = 1;
items_in_cart[77] = 2;
```

i get 78 but this array only have two elements

thank you

Comment: `Arrays` are not meant for `key-value` pairs. You are abusing arrays. Use objects instead.

Comment: for the first part, arrays are not supposed to be used like that in js, use object instead if you want to use custom keys... as for second part, everything from index 0 to 76 (excluding 50) is `undefined`, try `console.log(items_in_cart[75])`... that's because they are not initialized with any value.  Array being chain of elements, 77th index cannot be created without 76th even though it is empty, so your array length is 78 instead of 2

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in JavaScript are standard objects with special handling of a class of property names called [*array indexes*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#array-index) (names that are all digits in canonical integer form whose numeric value is `>=` 0 and `<` 2³²-1), special handling of the `length` property, and using `Array.prototype` (typically) as their prototype. Properties named by an array index name are called "elements." Other properties are just properties.

The `length` property of an array is always equal to the highest *array element index* the array contains plus one. In your first code block, there are no array elements (just non-element properties), so the `length` is `0`. In your second, the highest array element index is `77`, so `length` is `78`.

If you're going to use non-array-element properties as in your first code block, it's generally best to use a non-array object (`{}`), not an array `[]`.

If you want to know how many properties an object has, you can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (if you don't care about inherited or non-enumerable properties). That would be good enough to get you `2` for your initial code block:

```js
const items_in_cart = {}; // I've made this a non-array object
items_in_cart['rr'] = 1;
items_in_cart['mm'] = 2;
console.log(Object.keys(items_in_cart).length); // 2
```

Or you can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) (for the string-named ones) and/or [`Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertySymbols) (for the Symbol-named ones), which also don't include inherited properties but do include non-enumerable ones. You can get a count of all inherited enumerable properties by using a `for-in` loop. To get a count of **all** properties (whether own or inherited, enumerable or non-enumerable), you have to write a loop using `getOwnPropertyNames` and/or `getOwnPropertySymbols` on the object, then using [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf) to go to its prototype object, and so on until you reach the end of the prototype chain.

If you want to know how many *elements* a sparse array (like your second one) has, this is one of the **very** few places I might use `reduce` (probably by wrapping it in a function with a useful name like `getSparseCount`):

```
function getSparseCount(array) {
    // `reduce` only visits existing elements, not holes in a sparse array
    const count = theArray.reduce(c => c + 1, 0);
    return count;
}
```

```js
const items_in_cart = [];
items_in_cart[50] = 1;
items_in_cart[77] = 2;
console.log(getSparseCount(items_in_cart));

function getSparseCount(array) {
    // `reduce` only visits existing elements, not holes in a sparse array
    const count = array.reduce(c => c + 1, 0);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays dont support named entrys so you will need to change to an object, after that you can just check how many keys there are to get the amount of items:

```js
var items_in_cart = {};
items_in_cart['rr'] = 1;
items_in_cart['mm'] = 2;

console.log(items_in_cart)
console.log(Object.keys(items_in_cart).length)
```

Comment: Well, they _do_ support named entries (`console.log(items_in_cart['mm']);` but just not in the way you'd expect (TJ's answer).

Answer (score -3):

You are using the Array in the wrong way! Try using a dictionary for this purpose like this:

```
var items_in_cart = {};
    items_in_cart['rr'] = 1;
    items_in_cart['mm'] = 2;
alert(items_in_cart.length);
```